# Initializing properties with values stored in the project on a custom QgsMarkerSymbolLayer

Tags: pyqgis-3

I try to write my own `QgsMarkerSymbolLayer` as a plugin with PyQGIS. The symbol has a specific property (`"heading"` in this case). I follow [the sample from PyQGIS Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#working-with-symbols) and I replace `"radius"` with `"heading"`. The value of `"heading"`, modified with my custom `QgsSymbolLayerWidget`, is correctly stored in the project (qgs file).

When the project is re-open, which method must be overwritten for initialize the value of `"heading"`? The constructor of my own `QgsMarkerSymbolLayer` is always called with the default value.

I'm using QGIS 3.12.0.

Answer (score -1):

I found a mistake with my code in the method createSymbolLayer() of the "metadata" class :

```
r = float(props["rayon"]) if "radius" in props else 1000.0
```

I forgot to replace the second "radius" with "rayon".